# How to take the result of a System.out.Print and make it a String?

Tags: java

I want the output of each of the 5 System.out.Print's to be stored in the sentence(x) variables. Additionally I want to take the last word of each sentence (excluding the punctuation) and set those into their respective variables.

```java
public class WordGame 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        //Sets up Scanner
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declares the Variables
        int age;
        String name;
        String city;
        String college;
        String job;
        String animal;
        String petname;

        //Get's the user input and assigns it to name
        System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
        name = in.next();

        //Get's the user input and assigns it to age
        System.out.println("Enter an age under 18: ");
        age = in.nextInt();

        //Get's the user input and assigns it to city
        System.out.println("Enter your city: ");
        city = in.next();

        //Get's the user input and assigns it to college
        System.out.println("Enter a name of a college: ");
        college = in.next();

        //Get's the user input and assigns it to job
        System.out.println("Enter a profession: ");
        job = in.next();

        //Get's the user input and assigns it to animal
        System.out.println("Enter an animal: ");
        animal = in.next();

        //Get's the user input and assigns it to petname
        System.out.println("Enter a pet's name: ");
        petname = in.next();

        //Declares the Variables
        String sentence1;
        String sentence2;
        String sentence3;
        String sentence4;
        String sentence5;

        //Displays the Story using user inputs
        System.out.println("There once was a person named " + name + " who lived in " + city + ".");
        System.out.println("Even though " + name + " was only " + age + ", " + name + " went to college at " + college + ".");
        System.out.println(name + " graduated and went to work as a " + job + ".");
        System.out.println("Soon thereafter, " + name + " adopted a(n) " + animal + " named " + petname + ".");
        System.out.println(name + " and " + petname + " both lived happily ever after!");

    }

}
```

The output should look like: "(City) (College) (Profession) (Petname) after!"
ex. "Chicago Yale Engineer Sparky after!"

Comment: What is going wrong in your current solution?

Comment: `System.out.println()` is meant to output, not store values. Don't print the text directly, but store the text in variables first (which you can then print).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure the question, but instead of printing the sentence straight away store it as a variable then just print the variable. Then you are free to use the variables after.Think that might answer your question.

```
        String sentence1 ="There once was a person named " + name + " who lived in " + city + ".";
        String sentence2 = "Even though " + name + " was only " + age + ", " + name + " went to college at " + college + ".";
        String sentence3 = name + " graduated and went to work as a " + job + ".";
        String sentence4= "Soon thereafter, " + name + " adopted a(n) " + animal + " named " + petname + ".";
        String sentence5 =name + " and " + petname + " both lived happily ever after!";

    //Displays the Story using user inputs
    System.out.println(sentence1);
    System.out.println(sentence2);
    System.out.println(sentence3);
    System.out.println(sentence4);
    System.out.println(sentence5);
```

If you want to remove the punctuation after you have printed them you can do the following:

```
sentence1 = sentence1.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
```

Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

In addition to declaring a `String` for each line, you can put them all into a single `String` and use `\n` to go to the next line:

```
    //Displays the Story using user inputs
    String paragraph = 
    "There once was a person named " + name + " who lived in " + city + ".\n" +
    "Even though " + name + " was only " + age + ", " + name + " went to college at " + college + ".\n" +
    name + " graduated and went to work as a " + job + ".\n" +
    "Soon thereafter, " + name + " adopted a(n) " + animal + " named " + petname + ".\n" +
    name + " and " + petname + " both lived happily ever after!";

    System.out.println(paragraph);
```

This would also be easier to do overall if you used `String.format` or `System.out.format` so that you did not need to concatenate so many `Strings` together.

Note:  To ensure this works on all systems, you can also use `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `\n`.